# Using Python Tesseract to get text from image, but getting an error

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm attempting to use to Python Tesseract to get text fron an image on my macos desktop and am running into an error that I cannot figure out.  I'm running macos High Sierra 10.3.2

My directory is set to my desktop (where the image lives) and I already specified the path to my tesseract executable.

I'm running

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'))
```

and getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 140, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 116, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(status_code, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, u'File "/var/folders/cp/dg2snlxn2631h8jx1bwb7jk80000gn/T/tess_cK4lka.PNG", line 1 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character \'\\x89\' in file /var/folders/cp/dg2snlxn2631h8jx1bwb7jk80000gn/T/tess_cK4lka.PNG on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details')
```

Any idea what might be causing this and how to get around it?  Would be happy to provide any clarifying details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to render a Non-ASCII character. Try adding this to the top of your .py file to ensure UTF-8 encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

As stated by the error message, see [this](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more details.

Comment: What if I'm just running this from the terminal and not executing a python file?

Comment: You could try to convert to a bytearray using utf8 encoding:print(bytes(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('preview.png')), 'utf8'))

Comment: Running from a .py file with the line I posted on top gives the same error?

Answer (score 0):

User the unidecode library

```
from unidecode import unidecode
    .
    .
    .
    print unidecode(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```